# gulp-livereload for changed html files

Tags: gulp

I have a gulp file setup and it refreshes the browser fine when editing sass, however it ignores the html files and php files.
I have tried various solutions including the browser extension, but nothing seems to work.

This is my gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
image = require('gulp-image'),
notify = require('gulp-notify'),
livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
del = require('del');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
return sass('sass/style.scss', { style: 'expanded' })
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9',         'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4' ))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(''))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Styles task complete' }))
    .pipe(livereload());
});

gulp.task('image', function () {
gulp.src('library/images/src/*')
.pipe(image())
.pipe(gulp.dest('library/images'));
});

gulp.task('clean', function(cb) {
del(['library/css'], cb)
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
var server = livereload();
livereload.listen();
gulp.watch('sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
gulp.watch('images/src/**/*', ['image']);
// PLEASE TELL ME WHAT TO ADD HERE TO LISTEN TO HTML & PHP
});

gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function() {
gulp.start('sass', 'image');
});
```

I have also added this to the header of said files:

```
<script>document.write('<script src="http://' + (location.host || 'localhost').split(':')[0] + ':35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></' + 'script>')
</script>
```

THanks

Comment: This is the line I was missing: gulp.watch(['*']).on('change', livereload.changed);

Comment: I have also edited the above as there was an erroneous 'watch' which I believe wasn't helping.

Answer (score 0):

For HTML pages that are in the same folder, create a new task above the `watch` task:

```
gulp.task('html', function() {
  gulp.src('./*.html')
    .pipe(livereload());
});
```

Then add this task to `watch` as follows:

```
gulp.task('watch', function(){
  livereload.listen();
  gulp.watch('sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
  gulp.watch('images/src/**/*', ['image']);
  gulp.watch('./*.html', ['html']);
});
```

I have not tested this for PHP but it should be the same for these pages– add a new task called `php` and then add this line to `watch` :  `gulp.watch('./*.php', ['php']);`

By the way, I removed `var server = livereload();` from the `watch` task since it does not appear to be necessary.